# Where does the referenced variable come from in the following bind_result snip of code?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm learning prepared statements with mysqli, and I am having trouble figuring out where the variable `$row` comes from in the following code, originally posted by hamidhossain in a [comment on the `mysqli_bind_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#85470) manual page (see link for the full code).

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM sample WHERE t2 LIKE ?")) { 
    $tt2 = '%';
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $tt2); 
    $stmt->execute(); 

    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
    {
        # Where does $row come from?
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
    } 

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
        foreach($row as $key => $val) 
        { 
            $c[$key] = $val; 
        } 
        $result[] = $c; 
    } 

    $stmt->close(); 
}
```

In the full code, the first time the variable $row is mentioned is at the line:

```
$params[] = &$row[$field->name];
```

Where does this $row variable come from? I understand that you have to use `call_user_func_array()` but I do not understand where the variable $row comes from.

Comment: It doesn't come from anywhere: it is not initialized. However, the first time it's accessed like that it is made an array with that key. The same goes for `$c`. Sloppy code if you ask me.

Comment: Hey Wrikken, I don't quite understand what you mean by "the first time it's accessed like that". Also, how would you do it? I want to learn all best practices and never do anything sloppy. Thx!

Comment: If you just run the line (without anything else): `$arr = &$row["foobar"]; var_dump($row);`, you see that `$row` is 'magically created'. A simple instantiation (`$row=array();`, `$c=array();`) already helps the code a lot, but if you don't need to bind to explicit variables, you should just use [mysqli_stmt::get_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) and [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: Hey Wrikken, thanks so much for your explaination. I completely understand what you are saying. 

However, the part that I am having trouble with is trying to figure out where the $row variable gets its data and how this whole process goes about working to produce the end result. There has to be something that I am missing.

Comment: Once the while loop is run, the $row array exists, then each one of those references are being added to the $params[] array for each iteration of the while loop. But once they are added as references as individual elements in the $params array, when I do a var dump on $params, it just says [0]=>
  &NULL for each element... then once I run the call_user_func_array(), and then do a var dump on $params, it then adds the type, but not the $field->name as the key. Shouldn't $arr = &$row[$field->name] put the field name as the keys of the $arr array?

Comment: in other words, I guess what I am trying to ask is "How does $row in the foreach loop mysteriously have the $key=>$value data in it... where at in this script did it get that information and place it in the $row array? Thanks so much for your help! This is driving me crazy!

Comment: AHHHHHH I figured it out finally!!!!!! For each individual reference that is being placed into the params array, when it gets to the bind_result function, it is taking $row[$field->name] and making that store the result of what is in that table, so later in the foreach, it is simply retrieving that same stored info :-) talk about confusing! but now it makes perfect sense! Thx so much for all your help in guiding my mind to figure this out!